# Change directory from batch file in Far console

Tags: batch-file, far

The command

```
cd %SOME_DIR%
```

in Far console changes current directory.

But executing the same command in batch script from Far does nothing. Is it possible to switch directory using batch script in Far?

Comment: what happens if you use `CD /D "SOMEDIRECTORY"`

Comment: Well, I have the same result. 
It changes from command line and nothing happens from bat file

Comment: Have you read @JosefZ's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Far manager](http://www.farmanager.com/index.php?l=en) runs a batch script (`.bat`) **in a child process** and [`cd` command](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) only modifies the environment of the current process. **It can't touch the environment of the parent**.